# Find & Replace regex in VSC - extract css attributes from html strings

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a dataset with a field of scraped markup containing inline css styles.
I would like to extract the background-image urls to return an array of url strings.
The other attributes aren't consistent so simple find and replaces are no good here.
The data is a CSV so I'd like to do this with Find + Replace regex in a text editor (Visual Studio Code in this instance).

Note the original question was closed as I wasn't specific about the solution. It should be a regex for a text editor, not a python solution.

example contents

```
[{"thumbs":"","thumbs-style":"background-image: url(\"https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15892_Listing_Thumb.jpg\"); width: calc(16.6667% - 8.33333px); height: calc(100% - 0px); left: calc(0% + 0px); top: calc(0% + 0px);"},{"thumbs":"","thumbs-style":"background-image: url(\"https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15899_Listing_Thumb.jpg\"); width: calc(16.6667% - 8.33333px); height: calc(100% - 0px); left: calc(16.6667% + 1.66667px); top: calc(0% + 0px);"},{"thumbs":"","thumbs-style":"background-image: url(\"https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/13878_Listing_Thumb.jpg\"); width: calc(16.6667% - 8.33333px); height: calc(100% - 0px); left: calc(33.3333% + 3.33333px); top: calc(0% + 0px);"},{"thumbs":"","thumbs-style":"background-image: url(\"https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/7902_Listing_Thumb.jpg\"); width: calc(16.6667% - 8.33333px); height: calc(100% - 0px); left: calc(50% + 5px); top: calc(0% + 0px);"},{"thumbs":"","thumbs-style":"background-image: url(\"https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15893_Listing_Thumb.jpg\"); width: calc(16.6667% - 8.33333px); height: calc(100% - 0px); left: calc(66.6667% + 6.66667px); top: calc(0% + 0px);"},{"thumbs":"","thumbs-style":"background-image: url(\"https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15894_Listing_Thumb.jpg\"); width: calc(16.6667% - 8.33333px); height: calc(100% - 0px); left: calc(83.3333% + 8.33333px); top: calc(0% + 0px);"},{"thumbs":"","thumbs-style":"background-image: url(\"https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15895_Listing_Thumb.jpg\"); width: calc(16.6667% - 8.33333px); height: calc(100% - 0px); left: calc(100% + 10px); top: calc(0% + 0px);"},{"thumbs":"","thumbs-style":"background-image: url(\"https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15896_Listing_Thumb.jpg\"); width: calc(16.6667% - 8.33333px); height: calc(100% - 0px); left: calc(116.667% + 11.6667px); top: calc(0% + 0px);"},{"thumbs":"","thumbs-style":"background-image: url(\"https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15897_Listing_Thumb.jpg\"); width: calc(16.6667% - 8.33333px); height: calc(100% - 0px); left: calc(133.333% + 13.3333px); top: calc(0% + 0px);"},{"thumbs":"","thumbs-style":"background-image: url(\"https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/7909_Listing_Thumb.jpg\"); width: calc(16.6667% - 8.33333px); height: calc(100% - 0px); left: calc(150% + 15px); top: calc(0% + 0px);"}]
```

I need to reduce it to an array of url strings like this

```
["https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15892_Listing_Thumb.jpg","https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15899_Listing_Thumb.jpg","https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/13878_Listing_Thumb.jpg","https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/7902_Listing_Thumb.jpg","https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15893_Listing_Thumb.jpg","https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15894_Listing_Thumb.jpg\","https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15895_Listing_Thumb.jpg","https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15896_Listing_Thumb.jpg","https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/15897_Listing_Thumb.jpg","https://www.widgets.com/assets/siteimages/Listing/7909_Listing_Thumb.jpg"]
```

Comment: your source is NOT a CSV file

Comment: I guess there's no solution to your requirement. Maybe it's a good idea to be open for different solutions to get your result

Comment: that's an example one line of the text file

Comment: I'm writing this in javaScript with splits instead, was hoping there was a quicker way in the text editor. I'm sure the Python answer would have been simpler but not got time to learn Python set-up today!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex that does what you want, see [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/5C1rju/1).

Find:

```
(\{"thumbs.*?"background-image: url\(\\)("[^"]*)\\.*?(,)(?=\{"thumbs)|(\{"thumbs.*?"background-image: url\(\\)("[^"]*)\\[^]]+
```

Replace: `$2$5"$3`   <= there is a space at the end of the replace to separate the array entries if you want it.

This will put in one extra space at the very end before the closing array bracket - but that is very minor and could easily be removed if necessary.

Essentially the regex breaks up each `thumbs` object into three components: before the url, the url and after the url up to the next `thumbs` object.

It uses a positive lookahead `(?=\{"thumbs)` to determine where the next `thumbs` object begins.  Because the last object will not have a next object, the regex contains an alternation

`|(\{"thumbs.*?"background-image: url\(\\)("[^"]*)\\[^]]+`

to catch that last url (without matching the closing `]`).  See the regex101 link for more explanation.